# AWS Config recorder stuck at "Taking inventory..." status

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-config

Today, when I went to AWS Console -> AWS Config -> Settings, and turned off the recorder then turned it back on.

Then the settings page got stuck at "Taking inventory..." status for many hours.

[image]

I can't edit the recorder now. Does any one know how to solve this problem?

AWS Config rules can't work if the recorder is not turned on.

I've tried running `aws configservice stop-configuration-recorder --configuration-recorder-name default` command to change the status of the recorder, but this doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Running `aws configservice delete-configuration-recorder --configuration-recorder-name default` command can successfully delete the recorder.

Then the only thing I have to do is recreate the recorder and AWS Config rule.